# ASP.NET: Making a synchronous controller for an asynchronous action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a need, for sake of backwards compatibility, to create a controller action for an asynchronous operation.

For some background, when the asynchronous operation is completed, a database record will be modified that says the operation has completed.

Can I write a controller action with a loop utilizing a Thread.Sleep() and query the database each iteration, checking to see if that record has been processed?

If there are any other ways to accomplish this, keeping in mind the constraint that this must be synchronous, I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: Show us how the asynchronous operation is started

Answer (score 0):

You can do a recursive function.

On complete of the async function, call the function again with different parameters.

Thread.Sleep will not work (it will initially, but anything that takes longer than the sleep length will send it all to bother)